intellij idea debug Could not find or load main class
I want to start using intelijj, but I'm having a lot of difficulty debugging, and I haven't found the reason anywhere,
I'm trying to debug a file with main, using f5, as in print:


Error: Could not find or load main class net.sf.l2j.loginserver.LoginServer Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.l2j.loginserver.LoginServer

I don't know why, could anyone help?

Is the Java file located in a source folder? If so, can you show it?

Try to specify the module where it now says "module not specified".

Set the value of Working directory to $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$.
